# "./toolchain build kivy" gives an error on Mac OX X 10.8 despite following the tutorial

Tags: macos, kivy

I'm trying to build kivy for iOS. Following the [tutorial in kivy's guide](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html), I enter command:

```
$./toolchain.py build kivy
```

But it outputs this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./toolchain.py", line 173, in <module>
 class ArchSimulator(Arch):
File "./toolchain.py", line 178, in ArchSimulator
 sysroot = sh.xcrun("--sdk", "iphonesimulator", "--show-sdk-    path").strip()
File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 1021, in __call__
 return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 486, in __init__
 self.wait()
File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 500, in wait
 self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
 raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_64: 

RAN: '/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path'

STDOUT:


STDERR:
 xcrun: error: unrecognized option: --show-sdk-path
Usage: xcrun [options] <utility> ... arguments ...

Find and execute the named command line utility from
the installed Xcode.

Options:
 -h, --help           show this help message and exit
 -v, --verbose        show verbose logging output
 --sdk <sdk name>     find the tool for the given SDK name
 --toolchain <name>   find the tool for the given toolchain
 -l, --log            show commands to be executed (with --run)
 -f, --find           only find and print the utility path
 -r, --run            find and execute the utility (this is the default behavior)
 -n, --no-cache       do not use the lookup cache
 -k, --kill-cache     remove any existing cache file (and perhaps recreate)
```

I'm using Mac 10.8 (on vmware) + Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Please link to the tutorial you used and put your command in a code block or backtics.

Comment: "./toolchain.py build kivy" :http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

Comment: Okay, I added that to your question; when you installed the prerequisites `autoconf automake libtool pkg-config` and `cython` was everything fine? I can't try this on 10.10 because it comes with `pip` already, which is a tad different from homebrew's `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [iOS prerequisites](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios-prerequisites.html#packaging-ios-prerequisites) for kivy states that it assumes you have Mac OS X 10.9 and Xcode 5.1 or better in order to proceed.
I suspect this os's version of Python won't run cython properly.
Try running `cython` and `tools/cythonize` to check that cython is up and running.
Lastly I think the [kivy user's group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kivy-users/build$2010.8/kivy-users/J1tvgCCvzv4/oiPNj_p6rIsJ) would be best able to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Oh. Please, link download xcode 5.1( sorry about my english).

Comment: I believe versions of Xcode move with OS X releases, so you may not be able to install 5.1 on 10.8 but to try, you'd just go to the app store for Xcode and see what version it'll let you get. Here's the release notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5_1.html and here's the app store link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12 individual (later version) download dmgs are here: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: Thanks. I'm successful !